# Sum only if corresponding cell is a number, and if not, allocate remaining % to other values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need your help. Below you see two columns.
I want to multiply the number in column A with column B and calculate the overall sum.
(2 x 20%) + (4 x 33%) + ... = 3,02

[image]

- If value in column A is not a number --> ignore this value
- also, allocate the %-value of the ignored value equally-weighted to the other ones

**Example:**

[image]

Allocate the 20% to the four other %-values equally, since this row is not a number, but "-". So 33% + 5%, 12% + 5%, ... and do the calculation all over again with new %

(4 x 38%) + (5 x 17%) + ... = 2,62

I really am a beginner at this.

thank you :)

Comment: when I add up (4 x 38%) + ... + (1 * 35%), i get 3,52. If you want 2,62 (not i.e. not allocating the remaining 20% to the other %-values equally) then use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5,B1:B5)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your final sum is incorrect:

```
(4 x 38%) + (5 x 17%) + ... = 2,62
```

Should be 3.52

You can do this with a SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    $A$2:$A$6,
    $B$2:$B$6+((SUM($B$2:$B$6)-SUMIFS($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,">0"))/COUNT($A$2:$A$6))
)
```

This multiplies each value in the first column by, the second column plus the proportional % of any non numeric qty's.

It calculates the proportional % by taking the total of all % and minusing those with a qty  greater than zero. it then divides that by the count of numeric qty's.

I hope that makes sense.